# Why can't grub boot Windows directly?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

According to Wikipedia, LILO used to be the default boot loader for most Linux installs, and could boot Windows.  Grub, however, can't boot windows directly, but rather calls the Windows boot loader, which then boots Windows.

My question is this: why did they take away the ability to boot directly to Windows from GRUB?  It's not the end of the world having to go through two boot loaders, but it still seems like a regression.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LILO_(boot_loader)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders (This indicates that LILO boots to windows and linux)

Comment: I don't think LILO ever did anything more than redirect booting, so it didn't bypass NTLDR or anything. So they both do exactly the same thing basically. Unless something happened in the end days of LILO that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Ok - that wikipedia page should be updated!

Comment: Windows must be booted using its own bootloader: https://superuser.com/a/735401/288895

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to boot Windows 8.1 without its own bootmanager?](https://superuser.com/questions/729264/is-it-possible-to-boot-windows-8-1-without-its-own-bootmanager)

Answer (score 1):

Grub 2 (not Grub Legacy) can boot Windows directly if you mean directly launching the `ntldr` without loading the *partition boot sector*:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntldr
root=(hd0,n) # replace n with your partition
ntldr ($root)/ntldr
boot
```

Both versions of Grub may *chainload* the partition boot record (which then loads `ntldr`):

```
root=(hd0,n)
chainloader +1
```

Comment: Since Vista bootmgr is used instead of ntldr

Comment: Yes the above equally applies to bootmgr too.

Comment: the line `ntldr ($root)/ntldr` in your code won't apply for bootmgr