# Grub latching-entry / booting Windows directly with Grub

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub

I have a rather complicated setup. On my PC I have a combination of 2 Linux Distros as well as 2 Windows Installs. I use this to split the different things I do to different versions of OS such that I do less procrastinating (it really helps by the way).

Now booting my Linux to do some work is super easy, I just boot the PC and the default values take care of booting the right OS. Booting into my Work windows works also rather good as I just have to select that I want to boot into windows in Grub and then just wait.

The issue that I have specifically is my Gaming install of Windows. I set it not as the default in the windows boot manager. Now the problem is, that when I want to boot into it, I have to do the following.

1. Wait for Grub to load.
2. Select Windows Boot Loader
3. Wait for the Windows boot loader
4. Select the Gaming version of Windows
5. Wait like a minute with the spinning wheel of Windows
6. Then the PC reboots and goes back to Grub
7. Select Windows again
8. I'm in the OS

With the Work Windows install its just the steps 1 and 2 and from there on it just boots in like 30s.

I see three solutions to my problem.

1. I get Grub to boot Windows directly without the Windows boot loader. The question is just how? I've not seen anybody achieve this online. And it seems nearly impossible without hacking Windows itself.
2. Have a "latching" Grub (i.e. have Grub remember what Selection I made last and then continue to boot this as default unless it is changed when the Grub Bootloader is present.)
3. Install a second version of the Windows Bootloader so I don't have this annoying "look back" with the reboot for the Gaming install.

Now my question is, what option would you recommend?

1. Seems impossible without huge time and development resources but I seem to find conflicting statements (Pro: [Why can't grub boot Windows directly?](https://superuser.com/questions/957658/why-cant-grub-boot-windows-directly), Con: [Is it possible to boot Windows 8.1 without its own bootmanager?](https://superuser.com/questions/729264/is-it-possible-to-boot-windows-8-1-without-its-own-bootmanager)).
2. Could be possible but I haven't found anything about it if it should be an option already.
3. Seems to be the reasonable solution to my problem.

Thank you for your time

AliSot2000

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some sleep-deprived googling I found the solution.

Option 2 is absolutely doable. The only thing is not to search for "latching-entry" when googling. Apparently if I had just googled a more verbose question than like "grub remember last choice" I would have totally found a solution instead of myself searching for latching grub entry, state retention grub, ...

So unless option 1 becomes available, I'm gonna stick with option 2.

And here's another post on how to get this to work.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/148662/how-to-get-grub2-to-remember-last-choice